# Call a function of contract A from a view function of contract B

Tags: solidity, error

I have a contract A, with a view function, which is calling another view function from contract B.

I'm getting: TypeError: Function declared as view, but this expression (potentially) modifies the state and thus requires non-payable (the default) or payable.

I understand the error, because a view function cannot modify the state, but they do not. The only solution is to remove "view" keyword, and when calling that funcion (that does not modify any state) I have to make a transaction, paying gas.

Can a view function call functions from another contract?

Thanks

Comment: Please, can you share your smart contract code?

Comment: Use .staticcall instead of .call. I _think_ it should do that automatically though, as long as the function you're calling is marked as `view` in your interface.